# How to set variable from imported data

Tags: import, data, variable, index

I have an excel file i would like to import as data in mathematica with 3 columns like below:

Column 1: the nodal numbers
Column 2: the values of mx
Column 3: the value of mxy

Once ive imported the data, i would like to save it as a variable, such that mx[13] would equal to the value of mx for the nodal 13 or mxy[2] would equal to the value of mxy for nodal 2. I cannot save it straight away as some nodal numbers are skipped.

Thank you

Comment: Try mx = `Import[filename]`.

Comment: I cant do that becauae some nodal numbers are missing. Importing would just name it as mx[1], mx[2], mx[3] and so forth. But if number 2 is missing, i'd have to skip mx[2]

Comment: Well then, you'll have to provide a sample of your file, since you haven't provided enough information to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I do after I `Import`a spreadsheet is check its dimensions, like this

```
xlsx = Import["/path/to/filename"];
Dimensions[xlsx]

(*  {1,4,3}  *)
```

This tells me there is one spreadsheet, and it has 4 rows and 3 columns.
To see the data, I would evaluate

```
nSheet = 1;
Dataset[xlsx[[nSheet]]]
```

That would give me a nice view of the data on the selected sheet.  When I look at the data I notice things like whether the node numbers are `Real` or maybe some of my values are text.

There are 2 ways to get the row for node 13, say.  One way is

```
node = 13;
First[Select[xlsx[[nSheet]], First[#] == node &]]
```

This returns only the first row that has a value in first column that is numerically equal to the node number.  This form works when we give an integer node number, but the data contains real values for the node numbers.  If the node numbers were text `Strings`, this would not work.  We can use this to define a function, `mx` that picks the second column of the row, as

```
Clear[mx]
mx[n_] := First[Select[xlsx[[nSheet]], First[#] == n &]][[2]]
```

The other way to select an entire row with the given node number is

```
FirstCase[xlsx[[nSheet]], {1.0 * node, ___}]
```

Now that may look strange, multiplying the node number by one, but we do that to convert from integer to real, because this method is based on matching patterns, not on numerical equality.  We could make function to pick the third column of the row like this

```
Clear[mxy]
mxy[n_] := FirstCase[xlsx[[nSheet]], {1.0 n, ___}][[3]]
```

Which way is better?  Personally, I would use the first method, based on `Select` for both `mx` and `mxy`.  If the node numbers in the spreadsheet were of type `String`, then I would use something similar to the second method, maybe.

There are some other ways to do the same thing.  For example, we could create a `SparseArray` for `mx` and another `SparseArray` for `mxy`.  Or, we could create two `Associations` or we could create `Datasets` with named rows.  I like the `Select` method because it is easy to understand and easy to code.  As long as the `Select` method works on the data in the spreadsheet, try to use it.

Comment: thank you! this is what i was looking for.. I used the select option

Answer (score 0):

Use `Import` to import your raw data from file, then use something like the following function to assign to the indexed variables `m[...]`. Below I use some made up data as your `raw` data; in your case that would be your actual data coming from `Import`:

```
raw = {{1, 3, 4}, {2, 5, 6}, {4, 7, 8}};
(mx[#1] = #2)& @@@ raw;
```